# Is there a way to know if a unittest class is done with all the tests?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class that implement unittest.TestCase; I would like to know when all the tests has been executed; and perform some operation.

Although I can't see how can I get this info; the class does not seem to have a clue about the number of tests, or at least I was not able to find out where this info is hidden.

I would like to do a simple check, so I can trigger another class in the same file, to perform some analysis and formatting data. Am I looking for something that in fact is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special class method for that - [`tearDownClass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass):

> A class method called after tests in an individual class have run.

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("All the tests in this class are done")

    def test_something(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_something_else(self):
        self.assertFalse(False)
```

Comment: I see, so there is a teardown(), called after each test, and a teardownclass() that is used for the class itself; thanks!